# Changing HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to create a 'circle calculator' which will take user input through a form and return them the area and circumference of the circle.
It all works except for displaying the result in the paragraph with the ID "circleData". It displays for a fraction of a second after submitting the form then disappears.

I would like the result of the Circle methods (the variable "text") to remain in the paragraph until the user submits the form again (when it should fill with the new data).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A Circle Calculator</h1>
    <form name="Circle" onsubmit="printCircle()" method="post">
      Enter the radius:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Radius"><br><br>
      Enter the units:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Units"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    <p id="circleData"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Circle = function(radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    Circle.prototype = {
      get _radius(){
        return this.radius;
      },
      get _area(){
        return Math.PI * (this.radius * this.radius);
      },
      get _perim(){
        return this.radius * (Math.PI * 2);
      },
      set _radius(radius){
        this.radius = radius;
      }
    }
    var aCircle = new Circle();
    var printCircle = function(){
      aCircle._radius = document.forms["Circle"]["Radius"].value;
      var units = document.forms["Circle"]["Units"].value;
      var text = "A circle with the radius of " + aCircle._radius + units + " has a circumference of " + aCircle._perim.toFixed(2) + units + " and an area of " + aCircle._area.toFixed(2) + units;
      document.getElementById("circleData").innerHTML= text;
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because `form` is submitted. Use `return false;` at the end of the `printCircle()`  or `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Tushar That would perfectly reasonable as an answer rather than a comment. You might want to re-submit it as an answer so we can give you more reputation points by up-voting it & maybe having it accepted.

Comment: While the other answers are correct, this will also display your desired result, only without submitting your form and goes directly to computation:

    `...
    <form name="Circle" method="post">
      Enter the radius:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Radius"><br><br>
      Enter the units:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Units"><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="printCircle();" ><br>
    </form>
    <p id="circleData"></p>
    ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onsubmit="printCircle();return false;"
```

Comment: This is correct if the function does not encounter error during runtime. However if it does, the `return false;` will not fire because the `onsubmit` will halt and return at the line of error and wont receive the `false` flag return after `printCircle();`, and continues to do its normal job, submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return false;` in your function.

```
var printCircle = function(){
      aCircle._radius = document.forms["Circle"]["Radius"].value;
      var units = document.forms["Circle"]["Units"].value;
      var text = "A circle with the radius of " + aCircle._radius + units + " has a circumference of " + aCircle._perim.toFixed(2) + units + " and an area of " + aCircle._area.toFixed(2) + units;
      document.getElementById("circleData").innerHTML= text;

      // prevent the form from its natural bahavior
      return false;
    }
```

The form's `onSubmit` event prevents the form from submitting the data if it gets a `false`.

```
<form name="Circle" onsubmit="return printCircle();" method="post">
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it the better and most effective way.

```
var printCircle = function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

And then:

```
<form name="Circle" onsubmit="printCircle();" method="post">
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)